# Guardar todos los valores de Radio en array php

Tags: php, jquery, array, checkbox

Desde ya agradezco su apoyo, estoy haciendo una aplicación donde **clono la primera fila de la tabl**a
y como nombres los input radio tienen un array; al mandar el form solo se almacena los valores chekados en el array; *quiera que los tambien guarde los no chekeados con ceros 0*;

```html
<td>
<input type="text" class="form-control txtfactor" id="txtfactor" name="txtfactor[]" >
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" class="form-control txtPeso" id="txtPeso" name="txtPeso[]">
</td>                    
<td>
<input type="radio" class="chkUnidadBase" id="chkUnidadBase" name="chkUnidadBase[]" value="1">
</td>
<td>
<input type="radio" class="chkUnidadRef" id="chkUnidadRef" name="chkUnidadRef[]" value="1">
</td>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" class="chkUnidadEstado" id="chkUnidEstado" name="chkUnidEstado[]" checked="checked" value="1">
```

//Codigo PHP

```
// Recibir datos  del Form
$cboUnidad      = $_POST['cboUnidad'];
$txtfactor      = $_POST['txtfactor'];
$chkUnidadBase  = $_POST['chkUnidadBase'];
$chkUnidadRef   = $_POST['chkUnidadRef'];
$txtPeso        = $_POST['txtPeso'];
$chkUnidEstado  = $_POST['chkUnidEstado'];

// recorro los array recibidos
for ($i=0; $i < count($cboUnidad); $i++) { 

    // Agrego al array los valores recibidos
    $datos_Unidades = array(
            "Factor"                => $txtfactor[$i],
            "UnidadBase"            => $chkUnidadBase[$i],
            "UnidadReferencial"     => $chkUnidadRef[$i],
            "Peso"                  => $txtPeso[$i],
            "Activo"                => $chkUnidEstado[$i]
    );
 }
```

- el problema es con los Radios no seleccionados; no se llega almacenar en el array vota el error:
  Notice: Undefined index: chkUnidadBase
  Notice: Undefined index: chkUnidadRe

Comment: Supongo que usas PHP para el guardado, agrega el código cuando recibes los  `input`

Comment: Ahi, esta el codigo con el que resibo los input's

Comment: ya lo agrege el codigo del POST

Comment: Debes agregar todo el código ya que en el que dejaste en ningún momento recibes por `POST` el radio `chkUnidadBase` ni `chkUnidadRef`

Comment: ahh perdon, estaba intenta otras formas y altere el codigo; ahora si

Comment: Creo que estas algo confundido ya que un `input` se recibe con `$_POST[]` y tu en ninguna momento lo estas recibiendo así, solo agregas la linea así `$chkUnidadBase[$i]`, no podemos saber de donde viene esa variable

Comment: si tienes razón; por buenas practicas hay que recibirlo con el POST, ya lo complete

Comment: observo que tienes 2 radios con nombres diferentes.
Para que puedas elegir entre uno o el otro. los radio se deben llamar iguales.

Comment: todos esos input son la primera fila de una tabla, con javascrit  clono toda la fila, de tal forma que todos tienen el smimo nombre; el problema qe tengo es cuando recibo con POST los chkUnidadBase[] y chkUnidadRef[] solo se almacena en el array los radios seleccionados; yo quiera que tambien se guarden con cero 0 los que no fueron elejidos

Answer (score 0):

Cuando el radio no se selecciona. no se envia a PHP. debes de comparar si existe en PHP,
algo asi.

```
if (empty($_POST["chkUnidadBase"])) {
    $chkUnidadBase= "no existe";// lo interpretas como no seleccionado
  } else {
    $chkUnidadBase= $_POST["chkUnidadBase"]; // si existe
  }
```

Comment: Comprendo, si fuese un solo radio lo manejaria de esa forma; pero mando de forma dinamica la cantidad de Radios; ahí quisiera capturar tambien los que no fueron seleccionados con ceros 0

Answer (score 0):

Cuando no se selecciona un `input type="radio"`, no se envía nada para esos campos en POST. A diferencia de otros elementos `input`, no hay un valor predeterminado, el campo simplemente no existe.

Para que funcione correctamente, debe verificar su existencia en el servidor.

```
$mi_radio = isset($_POST['mi_radio']) ? $_POST['mi_radio'] : 0;
```

Con esto evaluará si existe el elemento `$_POST['mi_radio']`, en caso de existir tomará su valor de lo contrario será cero.

En tu caso los recibes como arreglos y tienes un solo `for` para asignar todos los elementos por lo cual está validación debe ser así:

```
// Recibir datos  del Form
$cboUnidad      = $_POST['cboUnidad'];
$txtfactor      = $_POST['txtfactor'];
$chkUnidadBase  = isset($_POST['chkUnidadBase']) ? $_POST['chkUnidadBase'] : 0;
$chkUnidadRef   = isset($_POST['chkUnidadRef']) ? $_POST['chkUnidadRef'] : 0;
$txtPeso        = $_POST['txtPeso'];
$chkUnidEstado  = $_POST['chkUnidEstado'];    

// recorro los array recibidos
for ($i=0; $i < count($cboUnidad); $i++) { 

    // Agrego al array los valores recibidos
    $datos_Unidades = array(
            "Factor"                => $txtfactor[$i],
            "UnidadBase"            => isset($chkUnidadBase[$i]) ? $chkUnidadBase[$i] : 0,
            "UnidadReferencial"     => isset($chkUnidadRef[$i]) ? $chkUnidadRef[$i] : 0,
            "Peso"                  => $txtPeso[$i],
            "Activo"                => $chkUnidEstado[$i]
    );
 }
```

**Detalles en tu código**

Veo algunos detalles en tu código que pueden causar conflicto, uno de ellos es que al recibir el `$_POST['chkUnidadBase']` puede tener inconvenientes al ser arreglo dinámico, ya que como comento, si no se selecciona la opción el elemento no existe en `POST` por lo cual al pasarlo como arreglo no van a coincidir con los indices de los otros elementos, por ejemplo, si selecciona solo un radio no importando su posición siempre tendrá el indice 0.

```
[chkUnidadBase] => Array ( [0] => 1 )
```

Si deseas alguna recomendación para evitar esto, puedes agregar el código completo del formulario para saber como se genera y cuantos indices puede tener cada elemento.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, efectivamente si no se selecciona la opción del elemento no existe en POST, los lementos los genero clonando esa fila de inputs, la cantidad es dinamica;